# pulling from <span> tags froma website using PHP and cURL?

Tags: php, curl, html

This is the code I have so far thanks to some help from another post, however when I tried to change bits of it to try and make it work for another website I get this error:

```
Undefined offset: 0 in H:\xampp\htdocs\dsa\php2.php on line 16
```

Code:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://www.masterofmalt.com/contact-us/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) 
 {
echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

preg_match('/<span itemprop="name">(.*)<\/span>/iU', $page, $list);
echo $list[0];

 ?>
```

this is the original code that displayed the opening times

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://www.tesco.com/store-locator/uk/?bID=2136');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) 
{
echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

preg_match('/<div class="fb hours">(.*)<\/div>/iU', $page, $list);
echo $list[0];

?>
```

this worked fine, but when i changed the website and then changed preg_match to display some of the address on the site i get that error above

Comment: And? Does the template match the new websites html code? What did *you* try to rectify it?

Comment: what do you mean by does the template match the new websites html code? do you mean the preg_match part?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because there are no matches in your 'preg_match' query.  Therefore, when you try and print out '$list[0]', it is telling you that there is no array item with a key of zero.

I tried running your code and got a server error.

```
$page = curl_exec($curl);
echo $page;
exit;
```

Then look at what's being output.  It may be expecting more information in your cURL request.  For instance, when I go to that site, I get prompted to select my location and then it sets a cookie before I can see the page.  So maybe you need to pass along a cookie with your cURL request saying that you are from the United States or wherever you are.

Answer (score 0):

The page http://www.masterofmalt.com/contact-us/ does not allow you to fetch html via cURL.

If you `var_dump($page)` right after `curl_exec`, you get this this line along with some more information:

*An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.*

A quick search indicates that that means you can't get the HTML of the page via cURL. The problem seems to be on their side, not yours.